# Packing JAVA tests to test my APP in offline environment

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, jar, build

I have a java project (Huge one) that I'm want to deploy to an off-line environment.

This environment only has access to Nexus(artifact repository) but not to my git repository,
So I upload my app with a script, and I want to run tests on it - But I can't run the tests using the test source because I don't have it (No access to GIT).
What is the best way to pack the tests (in a jar file? UberJar?),
What is the best practice to do so?

The tests are Selenium tests, which needs a browser.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you can upload your app with a script; what prevents you from uploading a .git file? And pushing changes there later on? That would be my "best practice" here. You see - that is one of the advantages of git: it works fine "off-line".

Answer (score 1):

What sort of tests are you talking about here? If they are unit tests, then they should be run by the build process, either on your development environment or on a build server.

If they are integration tests then they probably require some set up like a test server, database, files etc. This usually means deploying the integration test module itself somewhere and running it against your core project.

In your situation this means you should do some extra work on the build of your integration tests so that a package is created which includes all necessary set up and application artifacts.

EDIT: in the case of frontend tests I would still package the tests as a separate module and deploy both the application under test and the selenium suite to the server, for example as a simple `.zip` file.

I would deploy the zip via SCP or some other direct file transfer. Nexus is not really suitable for this and the test artifacts will sit there in your repository taking up space and confusing people.

Another solution is to create a Docker container which contains all the stuff needed to run your tests, and just deploy this container to your server.

Comment: Docker container doesn't seem like a good idea because we will need to create a new image every time the tests are changing. I think I will go with the approach of creating a .zip file. So if I understand correctly you suggest that I will zip all the tests (source code + mvn pom's) and just get this zip from my artifact repository (Nexus)

Comment: No, I suggested to let the build create a suitable test artifact for you. Normally that would not contain source code, unless maybe interpreted code.

Comment: Using Docker like this is actually the intended usage: bundling up software and configuration in a VM for seamless deployment.